# GREG services bulk load approach

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I'm planning to get GREG from WSO2 as business service registry. We're currently storing services in a Spreadsheet as a delimited text file. Services are still abstract concepts (operations not).

Which is the best approach (painless, programming-less...) to do a bulk load of about 660 business services and 12000 operations?

Answer (score 0):

The most painless way probably is using the registry client. WSO2 provides a java based client you can use to easily access the registry. It won't be completely painless, but with a couple of lines of code you could easily add this information.

On other option would be to directly plug in to the underlying JCR repository or database, but than your entering the painful area I think.